# Dynamically create EventHandler for a dynamically created .NET CheckBox from Powershell

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have a Powershell script that creates a form with a panel:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$mainForm                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$mainForm.ClientSize             = '450,565'
$mainForm.text                   = "Instalación automatizada de software y componentes"
$mainForm.TopMost                = $False
$mainForm.ShowIcon               = $False

$lblApplications                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$lblApplications.text            = "Aplicaciones"
$lblApplications.AutoSize        = $True
$lblApplications.width           = 25
$lblApplications.height          = 10
$lblApplications.Anchor          = 'top,right,bottom,left'
$lblApplications.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(22,50)
$lblApplications.Font            = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

$pnlApplications                 = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Panel
$pnlApplications.height          = 125
$pnlApplications.width           = 415
$pnlApplications.Anchor          = 'top,right,bottom,left'
$pnlApplications.AutoScroll      = $True
$pnlApplications.location        = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(17,70)
...
```

The script dynamically adds checkboxes to the panel from an object:

```
$mainForm.Add_Load({ Initialization-Info; $mainForm.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Normal; })

Function Initialization-Info {
    # Fill applications list
    $verticalPosition = 15;
    ForEach ($ChocoPkg In $ChocoPackages) {
        $ckbApp                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $ckbApp.Text                    = $ChocoPkg.Desc
        $ckbApp.Tag                     = $ChocoPkg.Name
        $ckbApp.AutoSize                = $False
        $ckbApp.Width                   = 380
        $ckbApp.Height                  = 20
        $ckbApp.Location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,$verticalPosition)
        $ckbApp.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        # Add the new Checkbox
        $pnlApplications.controls.AddRange(@($ckbApp))
        $verticalPosition += 23;
    }
}
```

I need to create and EventHandler for each dynamically created CheckBox that calls a function, the function needs to know what CheckBox triggered the EventHandler to take an action.

I've tried this with no luck:

> OPTION1

```
    ForEach ($ChocoPkg In $ChocoPackages) {
        $ckbApp                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $ckbApp.Text                    = $ChocoPkg.Desc
        $ckbApp.Tag                     = $ChocoPkg.Name
        $ckbApp.AutoSize                = $False
        $ckbApp.Width                   = 380
        $ckbApp.Height                  = 20
        $ckbApp.Location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,$verticalPosition)
        $ckbApp.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        $ckbApp.CheckedChanged          += Update-SelectedPackages;
        ...

Function Update-SelectedPackages {
    Write-Output ("Changed checkbox: " + $this.Text);
}
```

> OPTION2

```
    ForEach ($ChocoPkg In $ChocoPackages) {
        $ckbApp                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $ckbApp.Text                    = $ChocoPkg.Desc
        $ckbApp.Tag                     = $ChocoPkg.Name
        $ckbApp.AutoSize                = $False
        $ckbApp.Width                   = 380
        $ckbApp.Height                  = 20
        $ckbApp.Location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,$verticalPosition)
        $ckbApp.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        $ckbApp.Add_CheckedChanged({ Update-SelectedPackages })
        ...

Function Update-SelectedPackages {
    Write-Output ("Changed checkbox: " + $this.Text);
}
```

> OPTION3

```
    ForEach ($ChocoPkg In $ChocoPackages) {
        $ckbApp                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $ckbApp.Text                    = $ChocoPkg.Desc
        $ckbApp.Tag                     = $ChocoPkg.Name
        $ckbApp.AutoSize                = $False
        $ckbApp.Width                   = 380
        $ckbApp.Height                  = 20
        $ckbApp.Location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,$verticalPosition)
        $ckbApp.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        $ckbApp.Add_CheckedChanged($ckbEventHandler)
        ...

$ckbEventHandler = [System.EventHandler] {
    Write-Output ("Changed checkbox: " + $this.Text);
}
```

Any idea?

> EDIT: Thanks to all, i've found the solution! Here is it:

```
Function Initialization-Info {
    # Fill applications list
    $verticalPosition = 15;
    ForEach ($ChocoPkg In $ChocoPackages) {
        $ckbApp                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $ckbApp.Text                    = $ChocoPkg.Desc
        $ckbApp.Tag                     = $ChocoPkg.Type
        $ckbApp.AccessibleDescription   = $ChocoPkg.Name
        $ckbApp.AutoSize                = $False
        $ckbApp.Width                   = 380
        $ckbApp.Height                  = 20
        $ckbApp.Location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,$verticalPosition)
        $ckbApp.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ckbApp CheckedChanged -Action { Update-SelectedPackages($Sender); }
        ...

Function Update-SelectedPackages ($ckbSender) {
    # Updated Checked state of Chocolatey packages
    If ($ckbSender.Tag -eq "ChocoPkg") {
        If ($pkgToUpdate = $ChocoPackages | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $ckbSender.AccessibleDescription }) {
            $pkgToUpdate.Checked = $ckbSender.Checked;
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I've found:

```
# Write your logic code here
Function Initialization-Info {
    # Fill applications list
    $verticalPosition = 15;
    ForEach ($ChocoPkg In $ChocoPackages) {
        $ckbApp                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $ckbApp.Text                    = $ChocoPkg.Desc
        $ckbApp.Tag                     = $ChocoPkg.Type
        $ckbApp.AccessibleDescription   = $ChocoPkg.Name
        $ckbApp.AutoSize                = $False
        $ckbApp.Width                   = 380
        $ckbApp.Height                  = 20
        $ckbApp.Location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,$verticalPosition)
        $ckbApp.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $ckbApp CheckedChanged -Action { Update-SelectedPackages($Sender); }
        ...

Function Update-SelectedPackages ($ckbSender) {
    # Updated Checked state of Chocolatey packages
    If ($ckbSender.Tag -eq "ChocoPkg") {
        If ($pkgToUpdate = $ChocoPackages | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $ckbSender.AccessibleDescription }) {
            $pkgToUpdate.Checked = $ckbSender.Checked;
        }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually came upon this issue a few weeks ago while building a form for network system maintenance. You're really close to correct, but there's one thing to change. Since the function Update-SelectedPackages is an external function (not actually bound to the checkbox), you have to pass the box object to it as a parameter. I hope this helps!

```
ForEach ($ChocoPkg In $ChocoPackages) {
        $ckbApp                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $ckbApp.Text                    = $ChocoPkg.Desc
        $ckbApp.Tag                     = $ChocoPkg.Name
        $ckbApp.AutoSize                = $False
        $ckbApp.Width                   = 380
        $ckbApp.Height                  = 20
        $ckbApp.Location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15,$verticalPosition)
        $ckbApp.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'

        # add a click function to the checkbox to be executed when clicked
        $ckbApp.CheckedChanged.add_click({
            Update-SelectedPackages($this)
        })
        ...

# pass $box element into the method so that the text can be referenced
Function Update-SelectedPackages($box) {
    Write-Output ("Changed checkbox: " + $box.Text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Bennett, I've tried your solution but no luck, I'm doing sobe wrong?

Here is the test https:// paste .ofcode .org/ uydF2jf9AxitYrgLB2Bb3B

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you allow parameters on the `Update-SelectedPackages` function like:

```
Function Update-SelectedPackages ([string]$boxText, [string]$package) {
    Write-Output "Changed checkbox: $boxText"
    Write-Output "ChocoPackage Name: $package"  # for demo added second parameter
}
```

and then build your checkboxes like:

```
Function Initialization-Info {
    # Fill applications list
    $verticalPosition = 15;
    ForEach ($ChocoPkg In $ChocoPackages) {
        $ckbApp                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.CheckBox
        $ckbApp.Text                    = $ChocoPkg.Desc
        $ckbApp.Tag                     = $ChocoPkg.Name
        $ckbApp.AutoSize                = $False
        $ckbApp.Width                   = 380
        $ckbApp.Height                  = 20
        $ckbApp.Location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(15, $verticalPosition)
        $ckbApp.Font                    = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,10'
        # add event handler using the values stored in this control
        $ckbApp.Add_CheckedChanged({ Update-SelectedPackages $this.Text $this.Tag })
        # Add the new Checkbox to the panel
        $pnlApplications.Controls.Add($ckbApp)
        $verticalPosition += 23;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Theo for your response. I've created this functional script to test your suggestion, but no luck (strip down the white spaces):

https:// paste .ofcode .org/ uydF2jf9AxitYrgLB2Bb3B

Comment: @EGerardoChinchillaM There was never a question about whitespaces in an url  but that's real simple: `$url = $url -replace '\s'`

Comment: No @Theo, strip down the white spaces in the URL that I posted to see the script example, this: https:// paste .ofcode .org/ uydF2jf9AxitYrgLB2Bb3B

Comment: @EGerardoChinchillaM `$ckbApp.Add_CheckedChanged({ Update-SelectedPackages($this) })` --> `$ckbApp.Add_CheckedChanged({ Update-SelectedPackages $this })` No brackets around $this. Also, move functions `Initialization-Info` and `Update-SelectedPackages` up to line 205